# what is a simple way to exchange array of clusters data between labview and python

Tags: python, json, xml, labview

Use case is processing some array of clusters data created in labview in python. Need pythonic representation of the array of clusters . Ideally should be able to post back a modified array of clusters of the same type back to labview.

Comment: The TestScript package (free, source-released) from Genuen has all this already done for you. http://www.genuen.com/products/testscript

Comment: The TestScript package seems pretty involved and complex for simple data exchange.

Comment: Well, yes; it can do more than the Python node in LabVIEW. It can do fully bi-directional function calls with data payloads.

Answer (score 2):

I started with XML and found it lacking support for arrays natively.  Next tried JSON format and it seems better because of native support for arrays. LabView flatten to JSON.vi (in LV pallete String /Flatten Unflatten String) to create a JSON string (that can be saved to a file if needed) and Unflatten from JSON.vi ( in same LV palette String / Flatten Unflatten String) to read back the python modified string back into LabVIEW array of clusters . Note: "Flatten to JSON.vi" does not support ENUM in clusters but does support Text Ring so right click, replace, String & ENUM, Text Ring for all ENUM clusters in Ring for all ENUM controls in cluster.

Comment: I concur that json is a good choice for generic interop. You may wish to take a look at JKI JSON (https://www.jki.net/tools), which supports enums and is less brittle on parsing than the built-in json functions.

Comment: yes JIK JSON tools is a better chocie than built-in json functions in LabVIEW for handling arbitrary cluster data.